# Contextual filter in block not working

Tags: 8, views

When I create a new view with only a block and use a contextual filter to generate an archive view for articles like `2016 (4)`, `2015 (8)` etc. I get the following error when loading the page where the block is included:
`InvalidArgumentException: You cannot create a URL to a display without routes. in Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->getUrl() (line 1926 of core\modules\views\src\ViewExecutable.php).`

When I add a page to the view the error disappears, but all the years are linked to the same URL of the view page, like 2016 (4) -> /archive, 2015 (8) -> archive

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no :(..........